# How can I replace a keyword but in HTML tags by JavaScript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Here's some codes:

```
<p id="para">
    This is my webpage:
    <a href="http://example.com">
        http://example.com
    </a>
    http://example.com
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var para = document.getElementById('para').innerHTML;
    var re = new RegExp(/(http:\/\/example\.com)/, 'gi'); // Should be fixed

    para = para.replace(re, '<strong>$1</strong>');

    // Result HTML code will be something like below:
    //
    // <p id="para">
    //     This is my webpage:
    //     <a href="&lt;strong&gt;http://example.com&lt;/strong&gt;">
    //         <strong>http://example.com</strong>
    //     </a>
    //     <strong>http://example.com</strong>
    // </p>
    //
    // So, I don't want to change the tag attribute,
    // and want to write regexp to avoid this problem.
</script>
```

Hopegully, this make sense. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry I've changed the code a bit. Added addtional `http://example.com` under the `a` tag. I'd also like to put `<strong>` tag here but `a`'s attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`/<a.+?>(.+)</a>/` is the regex you're looking for. With `gi` as flags.

**EDIT in response to the question update:**

```
var para = document.getElementById('foo');
para.innerHTML = ( para.innerHTML.replace(/[^"'](http:\/\/.+?)\s/gi, '<strong>$1</strong>'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your qiuck fix. Actually I've changed my question, so hopefully you could answer it :P Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to probably use 2 regexs one for the HTML encoded version and another for the non-encoded version.

The first one would be /(http:\/\/example.com)/

The second one would be /http:\/\/example.com(?=")/.   This one uses a lookahead.  It assumes you have " at the end of the URL.  You could also try a lookbehind but from what I recall support lookbehind is not always supported Javascript.  So lookahead might be the way to go.

Comment: You've got it backward: `(?=")` is a **lookahead**, and JS does support them.  What it *doesn't* support is lookbehinds.